# Using --build-arg to modify FROM clause in Docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

Say we have a Dockerfile like so:

```
FROM node:9
```

and we build it with:

```
docker build -t foo .
```

my question is - is there a way to change the FROM clause using a `--build-arg`, something like this:

```
ARG NODE_VERSION
FROM node:$NODE_VERSION
```

and the build that with:

```
docker build -t foo --build-arg NODE_VERSION="8" .
```

Comment: doing this however, would probably destroy any caching ability the image could otherwise do :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works exactly like you have proposed.  Given the following Dockerfile:

```
ARG base_image=alpine
FROM $base_image
```

I can build it like this and get an Alpine based image:

```
docker build -t test1 .
```

Or like this to get a Fedora based image:

```
docker build -t test2 --build-arg base_image=fedora .
```

As you say, changing the base image would invalidate the cache.

Comment: that is really cool thanks, I was trying `FROM node:$NODE_VERSION`, and it wouldn't accept a variable there.

Comment: so if I do `ARG base_image=alpine`, that means that `alpine` is just the default value, right?